# Facebook PHP API | Incorrect Friend Count

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm using this to get my friends from my profile:

```
$facebook_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

it works kinda well, except the Friend count does not seem to add up, at the moment i got 193 friends but it only get 189 in the $facebook_friends array. Does this has something to do with maintaining (server side) of profiles or privacy rights ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook users can opt out of the Facebook Application Platform:

[image]

Comment: uhm, kinda embarrassing, anyways thanks a lot - maybe someone will have the same question and can use it